Questions about the Tradviewn backtest
What are the conditions that are the closest to reality to do the backtest?
Bar magnifier ?
Recalculate after order filling ?
These 2 together should be as accurate as possible, but I don't think the results are right.
My strategy opens a new position at any point in the bar and not just at the end.
Can someone tell me which ones I should really mark to have a more accurate result ?
When I mark one and unmark the other and vice versa, the results are quite different.
I tried searching on various sites how best to do it but I couldn't find it

It looks like a code error, but you don't share the code.

In your condition of long or short, try barstate.isconfirmed

Try Fill Orders > On bar close
